# Unable to load DLL 'fbembed'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, firebird

I am not able to load a ddl even though i am having dat dll
and if am adding through a refrence It's showing

> A refernce to "Path\fbembed.dll" could not be added.
>   Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that is valid assembly or COM component.

Comment: Any particular reason you belive that this (potentialy part of Firebird SQL) DLL is managed assembly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lone fbembed.dll is not enough. The minimal set of files consists of:

```
icudt30.dll
icuin30.dll
icuuc30.dll
fbembed.dll                   
Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest
firebird.msg                               
msvcp80.dll
msvcr80.dll
ib_util.dll                   
Intl\fbintl.dll     (Intl -- it is a subdirectory)
```

Get them all from FB2.5 distributive and put near your executable.

If your database uses custom UDFs you will also need in UDF subdirectory with appropriate DLLs put there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place fbmebed.dll in the application path. For ASP.NET application it's the best idea to put it into the system folder. See also http://web.firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/blog/2005/11/how-to-use-embedded-firebird-in-aspnet.html